# Automatically displayed field in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a master detail form in Oracle APEX. The table has items: ID, NAME, PRICE, VAT, TOTAL_COST. Is there a possible way in Oracle APEX to make some items automatically filled up. For example, when user in form enter PRICE, the VAT and TOTAL_COST field automatically are calculated and displayed. Not after the user submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create "Set value" dynamic action(s) on item(s) which is (are) changed.

Comment: On PRICE or on VAT and TOTAL_COST? I've tried it but it's not working

Comment: On PRICE, if everything else depends on it.

Comment: Hello Mateja "it's not working" is not a good phrase when looking for answers from other people in a forum. It could mean anything - maybe your keyboard is broken ? Just kidding it probably isn't but if you want answers, then explain what you do with as much info as possible that could help others assist you in solving your issue.

Comment: I have tried following this tutorial: https://www.lrayner.com/post/dynamic-actions-set-value-oracle-apex-18-2      but still, it's not displaying anything

Comment: And I wanna do it on a detail page (interactive grid)

Comment: Hi Meteja, please set up an example on apex.oracle.com and provide us with developer credentials to the workspace. When ready, provide us with step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce the error.

Comment: @DanMcGhan did you have a look?

Comment: Just looked. You have a Set Value action that is running a PL/SQL function which runs two update statements. This is not how it's supposed to work. Why are you updating table values? I updated action's Set Type to SQL Statement and added a SQL query that I think is what you wanted based on the update statements (SQL Query can map multiple columns to multiple columns). However, there were no rows in STAVKA_RACUNA (the update wouldn't have updated anything) so it wasn't working. That's why I added the union - just to give you an idea. Have a look and let me know how it goes.

Comment: But it is returning 1 for PDV_STAVKE and 2 for UKUPNO_STAVKE always, it is not based on what I enter in the IZNOS_STAVKE field

Comment: Yes, I tried to explain that. Your code was doing updates on a table (STAVKA_RACUNA) that had no data. When I converted the updates to queries, I was getting nothing back. So I added a union on dual to demonstrate what would happen when you fixed what I believe is a bug. How are the calculations supposed to work? Are they dependent on STAVKA_RACUNA? If not, why where you updating that table before?

Comment: If you have look again you will see I have changed sql statement a bit. It is woriking on the Example. But, when I use that procedure on my original app, it returns un errror. Both apps are based on the same database.

Comment: @DanMcGhan did you have a look? :)

Comment: @MatejaK Sorry, I only just saw this. If you'd like to meet online so that I can see the app and offer suggestions, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/). If you do reach out, please include the URL to this Stack Overflow question.